# GCP error for network

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I received an error such as this when trying to create a TPU resource. I am new to GCP and could anyone please assist me? I try to find the tutorial too but of no luck. If anyone has any suggestions, please let me know. In the meantime, I would like to solve the below issue:

```
(gcloud.beta.compute.tpus.create) argument --network: Must be specified.
```

I am new to this stackoverflow too, please let me know if I asked at the wrong website and I will delete it.

Comment: You probably have a default network (called `default`) that you may use. Here is the documentation for the `gcloud beta compute tpus create` command (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/tpus/create). It explains the flags and arguments. You may prefer to use the Cloud Console to create TPUs. This will guide you in the available options and will help you succeed (https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/tpus/add)

Comment: Thank you, Sir. I will look into it right away.

Comment: Is your problem got resolved as guided by [DazWilkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/609290/dazwilkin)? If yes, please provide an answer to this thread stating how did you resolve the issue. This would help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the answer provided by [DazWilkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/609290/dazwilkin) in the comments which might be useful for other community users looking at this thread. When you are using the default VPC network which also called "default", you can use "default" with the "--network" flag while running the below command:

$ gcloud beta compute tpus create

"--network" flag specifies the network that this TPU will be a part of. If you are using any other network, please specify the network name with the "--network" flag.

You can find details of the different flags and its purpose in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/tpus/create). Google Cloud Console is another option to create TPUs if convenient for you. You can directly go to this link to add TPUs from [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/tpus/add)